# Inject text into a IWebElement's innerhtmlm, with javascript in c# selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am trying to inject some text into a textarea, on a webpage. I am using Selenium library for C#.

I have set the following

```
IWebElement captchaTokenField = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@id='g-recaptcha-response]"));
js.ExecuteScript(captchaTokenField.InnerHTML = $"{captchaResolveID.request}", 0);  // This line throws an error :S
```

Would appreciate if someone could show me the right way :D

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: I am sorry, wrong expression "error" to use, it is not valid Selenium code :S

Comment: unbalanced quotes here:  By.XPath("//textarea[@id='g-recaptcha-response]")... ExecuteScript method takes a string...you are currently sending it some objects... "InnerHTML" should be "innerHTML" I think...  "$" assumes some kind of jQuery object... I'd avoid that...

Comment: I recommend you get your "captchaResolveID.request" in a separate line.  Then build the string that will be your javascript.  Then send that to your executeScript function.   (No need for the ,0)...

Comment: If your code is throwing an error, please [edit] your question to include the error message and full stack trace.